# Installing DBD::Sybase on OS X with Homebrew fails to find freetds libraries

Tags: perl, makefile, homebrew, sybase, cpanm

I am installing  DBD::Sybase

I receive following error, after setting

```
export SYBASE=/usr/local/Cellar/freetds/0.95.80
```

and download freetds:

```
brew install freetds
```

Error:

```
Configuring DBD-Sybase-1.15 ... Can't find any Sybase libraries in /usr/local/Cellar/freetds/0.95.80/lib or /usr/local/Cellar/freetds/0.95.80/lib64 at Makefile.PL line 155, <IN> line 44
```

I believe I need to edit the makefile directly. Do I need to edit makefile? And could I use CPANM still. CPANM is under Brew (cellar).

```
/usr/local/Cellar/freetds/0.95.80/lib
├── libct.4.dylib
├── libct.a
├── libct.dylib -> libct.4.dylib
├── libsybdb.5.dylib
├── libsybdb.a
└── libsybdb.dylib -> libsybdb.5.dylib


 /usr/local/Cellar/freetds/0.95.80/
AUTHORS              ChangeLog            NEWS                 TODO                 etc                  lib
COPYING              INSTALL_RECEIPT.json README               bin                  include              share
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [a reported bug in DBD::Sybase on OS X](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=89816) which is causing your problem.

[One part of the configuration](https://metacpan.org/source/MEWP/DBD-Sybase-1.15/Makefile.PL#L143) thinks you're on Windows. Perl reports OS X as `darwin` and DBD::Sybase is checking for `/win/` as in `MSWin32` or maybe `cygwin`. As a result it looks for a `dll` directory, but falsely reports it's looking for `lib` and `lib64`.

The quick fix is to use `cpanm --prompt DBD::Sybase`. When it fails, `cpanm` will ask what to do.

```
Configuring DBD-Sybase failed.
You can s)kip, r)etry, e)xamine build log, or l)ook ? [s]
```

Tell it to `l)ook`. This will dump you into a shell with the unpacked source for DBD::Sybase. Use an editor to delete lines 143-145 in the Makefile.PL.

```
if ($^O =~ /win/i) {
  @libdir = ( 'dll' );
}
```

Then `exit` the shell. `cpanm` will ask you what to do again, tell it to `r)etry`. It should use your edited Makefile.PL.

Comment: That's the part I am unsure. So cpanm gets the files, and then after change what command would I run with new makefile? cpanm? and point to directory?

Comment: @paulj Don't touch the Makefile, that is generated by Makefile.PL. I've edited full instructions into the answer

Comment: It works to a point. So answer accepted. Wondering any way of skipping tests: The DBD::Sybase module need access to a Sybase server to run the tests, because they fail on test ms-sql-server.

Comment: For anyone else, I choose force install after tests failed. My perl dbi is running.

Comment: @paulj If you run `perldoc cpanm` for its docs you'll find `--notest`. If you want to connect to a MS SQL Server, you're probably better off with DBD::ODBC.